# Safely Confirm File Details

Tags: php

I'm trying to work out the safest way to confirm some details about an uploaded file - e.g. file extension, file size (bytes), file dimensions (if image), etc.

I've found several methods to get the extension but they all seem to be based on manipulating the file name, which is very trivial to fake.

For image dimensions I've been using getimagesize(). For file size I've been using filesize.

I'm working with sensitive data, so want to have every point of entry to the site secure. Is there a safer way to get all of this data on an uploaded file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A file extension *is **by definition** part* of the file name. Are you talking about the file's actual type?

Comment: Linked to wrong doc page, http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php. If they are always images.